# how to access other component in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, ref

I would like to ask if I have 3 components which are not parent-child(please don't ask me to join the 3 buttons into one component) relationship as below, I can use redux to edit value **input3** by clicking **button1**,

**what if I want to click button1 then show the value of input3 in a console.**

Should I use **ref** to do this? but they aren't parent-son and sibling relationship?

Thank you

---

Button1

|

Button2

|

Button3

---

**Components**

```
class Button1 extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                 <Button id="Button1" ></Button>
                 <input id="input1" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Button2 extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                 <Button id="Button2" ></Button>
                  <input id="input2" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}


class Button3 extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                 <Button id="Button3" ></Button>
                 <input id="input3" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**ReactDOM**

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
  <Button1/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('div1')
);

ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
  <Button2/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('div2')
);

ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
  <Button3/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('div3')
);
```

Comment: Why are you using 3 different renders and stores? Why it can't be one app? 

To make as you want you have to create one parent for all of those 3 components and keep there your state and pass values as props to children (and make inverse data flow as well). Please, read this [article](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html).

Comment: If you really want to, you can forward refs. Please read https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html